# Conditional Comments IE8: Works local, not when published

Tags: internet-explorer, comments, conditional-statements

I have two conditional comments which are used to accommondate older IE-browsers. They work perfectly when used on local development server but fail to work when published to a real server. The files are on the server and the paths are correct. I did a test and the IE-version is recognized. So what could cause the issue?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot-plugins/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Edit

Right, had a coffee break and blew off some steam. Looked at the source again and noticed the path was wrong when on the real server. One of these afternoon human quirks again.

Edit

Comment: I've never heard of conditional comments not working in this way. The syntax looks good. Have you checked the DOM in IE8 using the Developer Tools, to see what it thinks is on the page? You might try using `[if lte IE 8]` instead; it should work the same, but might be worth trying as a long shot.

Answer (score 1):

You have CAPITAL letter "S" in word /Scripts/
so localy it works but not on server. I guess UNIX matter.

So do not use CAPITAL LETTERS neither in your paths nor in your folder names:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqplot-plugins/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```